# Which of the following are linear transformations? (Matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, transformation

[image]

So I know that transformations follow a similar idea of checking for addition and scalar multiplication but I have not been able to successfully apply that logic to this problem. I do not understand how to check these choices for linearity. Can someone please help me understand how I should approach these problems so I can apply that logic to other similar questions?

Comment: Exactly the same way that you might when your vectors are simply tuples of numbers. Check that $T(aM+bN)=aT(M)+bT(N)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as an example, for option A....

$T(A)=A^T$ is linear. You can show this by talking about components.

$T(c a_{ij})=ca_{ji}$ or $cT( a_{ij})=ca_{ji}$

$T(a_{ij} + b_{ij})=a_{ji}+b_{ji}$ or $T(a_{ij} )+ T(b_{ij})=a_{ji}+b_{ji}$

For option C...

Any linear transformation can be represented by a matrix (and vise versa). So let $A^6=B$

Then, $T(A)=A^7=A^6A=BA$.
So it's linear too.

Try applying these techniques to the other ones.